# Есть ли тавтология в словах "...подтянем дружнее, друзья".

Tags: грамотная-речь, тавтология

В известной песне времён Великой Отечественной войны есть слова: "...О дружбе большой, о службе морской, Подтянем дружнее, друзья." Есть ли тавтология в словах "...подтянем дружнее, друзья"?

Answer (score 2):

Есть, но, как уже было сказано в одной из тем этого форума, не всякая тавтология - зло. Это скорее литературный прием, нежели грубая ошибка. Конечно, в большинстве случаев её следует избегать, но всё же она может стилистически подчеркнуть мысль.

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Слова разной сиысловой нагрузки. Петь дружно могут и не друзья, а друзья могут этого и не уметь. Ко всему прочему, "друзья" - обращение и у же этим обособлено по смыслу от остальной части.

Comment: А как же "о дружбе большой"? Разве это не тавтология к обращению?